# Finding Grandfathers birth certificate born in Lwów Poland

Tags: birth-records, poland

I'm trying to find my Grandfathers birth certificate, he was born in Lwów/ Lvov 1922 back when it was Poland.

I've searched both the Galacia Database and Jewish Gen including all the usual Ancestry.com, Findmypast stuff etc...

Unfortunately, I have found nothing, I have no idea of the village or what cemetery.

Any tips?

Comment: What year do you expect that his birth occurred in?  If it was before 1918 then, if you are comfortable to provide his name, that will be OK with respect to our Privacy Policy at the [help/on-topic], and may help us locate the record.

Comment: @PolyGeo Probably after 1918 or else he would have said he was born in Lemberg, Austria-Hungary :)

Comment: He was born in 1922 and also forced to serve in the Deutsche Volksliste.

Comment: Do you have a link to any evidence of decease for him? With something like a link to a death/funeral notice, grave location, etc the opportunity to provide his name here opens up.

Comment: Yes he died here in the UK, he came here after WW2.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? my grand father born same place around same time and never been able to trace or find anything? Abby

Answer (score 5):

If he was Jewish, try searching the All Galicia Database or the JRI-Poland Database under *his mother's maiden name*. Many Jews in this area of Galicia were assigned their mother's maiden name on official documents -- including birth certificates, marriage certificates, passports, Polish draft lists, etc. -- because the local authorities didn't recognize religious-only marriages if the couple didn't bother to go get a civil license, and many didn't bother.